# XMLParse Coldfusion 9 - Content Not Allowed In Prolog

Tags: coldfusion

I am trying to parse some data from Australia Post using Coldfusion, the code works perfectly when i'm using CF10 locally but the problem is that the servers i'm using are using CF9 and i'd rather keep them with 9.

When i try the code in CF9 i get "Content not allowed in prolog" no matter what i try, i managed to do a ReReplace when then threw the error of "Premature end of file" so i'm not sure what else to try also on the server it's using IIS6 i don't know if that's contributing to the issue

I've also connected the SSL certificate through the keystore as i read that could be an issue as well

```
<cfhttp url="https://auspost.com.au/api/postage/parcel/domestic/service.xml?from_postcode=2128&to_postcode=6000&length=96&width=8&height=5&weight=1.5" method="get">
<cfhttpparam type="header" name="auth-key" value="*******">
</cfhttp>

<cfset objBuffer = CreateObject(
"java",
"java.lang.StringBuffer"
).Init()
/>

<cfset objBuffer.Append(cfhttp.filecontent) />

<cfset xmlDoc =XmlParse(objBuffer)>

<cfdump var="#xmlDoc#">
```

Comment: Have you checked to see if there is any extra space at the beginning?   Maybe try trim () around the output.

Comment: It could be a charset problem too.  Try adding charset="UTF-8" to your cfhttp call.

Comment: Have you reviewed this article to see if it helps? http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1206-content-is-not-allowed-in-prolog-coldfusion-xml-and-the-byte-order-mark-bom.htm

Comment: @abbottmw THANKYOU this done the trick! can't believe it was something so simple!

Comment: Can someone post the actual solution here? Ben's site appears to be down and the answer isn't posted.